# Apache2 start error cannot load lobphp5.so

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have failure when i try to launch my apache2 server:

```
     apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php.load: Cannot
 load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server:
 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

In my /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ folder I have libphp5.6.so and libphp7.4.so

I tried to reinstall apache2, it says its already installed, don' t know what to do next

Thanks for your helps

Comment: change the line in `etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php.load` to reflect what you have (as so file)

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov i the php.load i have only those lines: <IfModule mod_php5.c>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php5
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</IfModule>
what should i change ? i don' t see any so file reference

Comment: So change the line where `.so` module is defined to reflect the reality